# Prove or find a counter-example: $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =\infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{f(1/x)}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove or find a counter-example:
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =\infty  \quad\text{if and only if} \quad \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{f(1/x)}=0$$

I think that the direction $\Rightarrow $ is true, while the other one is false, but I can't find a counterexample. Will someone please guide me through it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the claim is false. Take $f(x) = -x$, as a counterexample

Comment: I overlook that there is no absolute value, thanks.

Comment: @user284331 No problem. If the LHS was $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \pm \infty$ then it's true